# Javascript Price Calculation Errors

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, e-commerce, cart

Discount Calulation do not output.

(discount is supposed to subtract from Grand Total) 
Html

```
input name="discount" id="discount" type="text">   <button  id="record_button" onclick="recordToFilename();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Record" > Submit Discount </button>  
     <b id="discount">Discount</b>
```

Javascript

```
 function recordTodiscount() {
var input = document.getElementById('discount'),
    discount = input.value;
```

check the the [jsfiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/enm4yhdk/10/)

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "<strong>SubTotal</strong>: $" + salesTotal.toFixed(2); 
document.getElementById('taxtotal').innerHTML = "<strong>Tax </strong>: $" + salesTotal*0.13.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML = "<strong>Grand Total </strong>: $" + salesTotal*0.14 + salesTotal. toFixed(2);//grandtotal and tax total come out the same 
document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "<strong>Discount </strong>: $" + salesTotal*0.14 + salesTotal-discount.toFixed(2); //grandtotal and tax total come out the same
```

`<input name="discount" id="discount" type="number">`

Comment: Give consideration to the concept of operator precedence.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663414/how-to-add-tax-and-a-discount-code-to-this-cart#comment41929246_26663414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period operator has higher precedence than the mathematical operators, so the `toFixed` method will be applied before the addition. As that makes the second operand a string, the `+` operator will do string concatenation instead of addition.

You need parentheses to make the calculations happen before the `toFixed` call:

```
(salesTotal * 0.13).toFixed(2)

(salesTotal * 0.14 + salesTotal).toFixed(2)

(salesTotal * 0.14 + salesTotal - discount).toFixed(2)
```

You are using `0.13` when calculating the tax, and `0.14` when calculating the total, they should probably be the same.

Instead of adding the total and the tax, you can just add one to the constant that you are multiplying with, i.e `salesTotal * 0.14 + salesTotal` is the same as `salesTotal * 1.14`.

Comment: Yes it was the parentheses I was missing , I have not yet solved the discount part. I will repost after I use parentheses. Thanks

Comment: The grand total works , but i am having errors with my input field(discount) I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/enm4yhdk/7/)

Comment: @infinityswift: The `discount` variable is local inside the `recordToFilename`, so it won't be available anywhere else in the code. Also, you have some missing `</h4>` and `</h3>` tags in the code, so the discount input is inside the tax total element. You also have two elements with `id="discount"`.

Comment: Yes I fixed the `</h4>` tags>. I am not sure why the discount tag is not being processed. I have updated [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/enm4yhdk/10/)

Comment: @infinityswift: Because you get the value and put it in a local variable. When the function ends the variable goes away. Declare a variable for the discount at the top of the script like the other global variables that you use.